# Can I Create Nested Angular Component HTML Selectors?

Tags: nested, angular, selector, angular-template

Updated: Per Thierry Templier's response:

Below is essentially what I want to do, but unfortunately the inner components aren't rendering. Is there a way to nest components via their HTML selectors like so?

```
<custom-menu-bar-component (onCustomEvent)="handleEvent($event)">
    <custom-button-component></custom-button-component>
    <custom-dropdown-component></custom-dropdown-component>
</custom-menu-bar-component>
```

In my chrome debugger, I see only the outer component being rendered:

```
<custom-menu-bar-component>
    <div class="row">
        ** Nothing here, where my two inner components should be :(
    </div>
</custom-menu-bar-component>
```

And my components look like this:

CustomMenuBarComponent.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {CustomButtonComponent} from './CustomButtonComponent'
import {CustomDropdownComponent} from './CustomDropdownComponent'

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-menu-bar-component',
    directives: [CustomButtonComponent, CustomDropdownComponent],
    template: `
        <div class="row"></div>
    `
})
export class CustomMenuBarComponent {
}
```

CustomButtonComponent.ts:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'
import {CustomEvent} from './CustomEvent'

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-button-component',
    outputs: ['onCustomEvent'],
    template: `
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-gray" (click)="onItemClick()">
        <i class="glyphicon icon-recent_activity dark-green"></i>Button</button>
    `
})
export class CustomButtonComponent {
    onCustomEvent: EventEmitter<CustomEvent> = new EventEmitter();
    onItemClick(): void {
        this.onCustomEvent.emit(new CustomEvent("Button Component Clicked"));
    }
}
```

CustomDropdownComponent is nearly identical to the CustomButtonComponent, but with different text. I'm just trying to get this very simple example working before I start making these components more useful and reusable.

Is this kind of approach possible? I'm trying to make it easy for others to take these components and create more of my custom menu bars with ease and simplicity.

Comment: What do you mean by "nest components via their HTML selectors?

Comment: After your update it looks like my answer is still valid.

Comment: Ahhhh, yes! Thank you Gunter, I didn't see your answer there.

Comment: I had deleted it after a while because I wasn't sure what you were actually looking for, but after your edit it became clear.

Comment: For some reason the CustomEvent isn't getting propagated up to the parent of the CustomMenuBarComponent, but maybe that deserves its own question.

Comment: I guess moving `(onCustomEvent)="handleEvent($event)"` to the `<custom-button-component></custom-button-component>` element should do what you want. Events from `EventEmitter` don't bubble.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what your question is about but

```
<custom-menu-bar-component (onCustomEvent)="handleEvent($event)">
    <custom-button-component></custom-button-component>
    <custom-dropdown-component></custom-dropdown-component>
</custom-menu-bar-component>
```

requires `<ng-content></ng-content>` in the template of `CustomMenuBarComponent`

A bit of documentation can be found in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#aftercontent I had expected a bit more this was all I found.

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html might contain some helpful information as well.

**Update**

Moving `(onCustomEvent)="handleEvent($event)"` to the `<custom-button-component></custom-button-component>` element should do what you want. Events from `EventEmitter` don't bubble.

Answer (score 4):

In fact you have the error because you don't instantiate your `EventEmitter` in the `CustomButtonComponent` component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class CustomButtonComponent {
  onCustomEvent: EventEmitter<CustomEvent> = new EventEmitter(); // <-----
  (...)
}
```

Otherwise your code seems correct.

**Update**

You need to use `ng-content` to include your sub components into the `CustomMenuBarComponent` one.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-menu-bar-component',
  directives: [CustomButtonComponent, CustomDropdownComponent],
  template: `
    <div class="row">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class CustomMenuBarComponent {
}
```

Comment: Yes Exactly Eric ! I went down to that line, saw `EventEmitter<CustomEvent>` and skipped the line but didn't notice new `EventEmitter` part is not there. `Eagle Eyes - Thierry`...

Comment: Ohhhhh, yes, thank you! Instantiating my EventEmitter gets me past that console error. Unfortunately, the inner components aren't being rendered. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: I think that you need to leverage `ng-content` for this. I updated my answer accordingly...